# REST in lift 2.0 + Scala 2.8

Tags: rest, scala, lift

I can see from release notes and such that there has been 
many improvements in lift 2.0 for building REST stuff,
but I'm unable to find what has been done or how to 
use the new stuff compared to the old.

Does anyone know of such documentation, blog entries, examples
or similar for how to use REST in lift 2.0.

Ideally I would like something along the lines of the links below 
updated for lift 2.0, or something similar.

Perhaps someone here have such examples handy or know where
to find it?

http://blog.m1key.me/2010/07/rest-with-scalas-lift-framework-part-1.html
http://blog.m1key.me/2010/07/rest-with-scalas-lift-framework-part-2.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm a REST-enthusiast in general and currently evaluating various aspects of Lift's support. I've recently blogged by thoughts on URI matching and Content Negotiation [here](http://www.suryasuravarapu.com/2010/08/lift-and-rest-uri-matching-and-content-negotiation.html) and [here](http://www.suryasuravarapu.com/2010/08/lift-and-content-negotiation.html). This is an ongoing series at this moment.

I really like what I see so far. The framework is very flexible. Even if you find an aspect of REST-support is missing you can extend the functionality with reasonable effort.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things have changed which make REST APIs a lot easier to create.  Here are two links to articles which describe the new methods for building them.  You should also look at the google group as there are lots of examples in the archives:

- http://blog.getintheloop.eu/2010/3/29/multi-format-rest-services-with-lift
- http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/REST_Web_Services